# ErrorException Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to php. While learning and writing some code, I ran into this error "ErrorException Undefined offset: 1". Here are the codes that I edited that resulted in this error:

WELCOME.BLADE.PHP

---

```
   @section ('title')
welcome!
@endsection


@section ('content')
@if(count($errors)>0)
<div class = "row">
    <div class= "col-md-6">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all()as $error)
                <li>{{$error}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-6">
        <h3> Sign Up </h3>
        <form action ="{{route ('signup')}}" method = "post">
          <div class = "form-group">
                <label for= "email"> your E-mail </label>
                <input class = "form-control" type="text" name = "email" id= "email">
          </div>
          <div class = "form-group">
                <label for= "first_name"> your first name </label>
                <input class = "form-control" type="text" name = "first_name" id= "first_name">
          </div>
          
          <div class = "form-group">
                <label for= "password"> your password </label>
                <input class = "form-control" type="password" name = "password" id= "password">    
          </div>
          <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">submit</button>
        <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value="{{Session::token() }}">
        </form>
                
</div>
<div class = "col-md-6">
    <h3> Sign In </h3>
        <form action = "{{route ('signin')}}" method = "post">
          <div class = "form-group">
                <label for= "email"> your E-mail </label>
                <input class = "form-control" type="text" name = "email" id= "email">
          </div>
          
          
          <div class = "form-group">
                <label for= "password"> your password </label>
                <input class = "form-control" type="password" name = "password" id= "password">    
          </div>
          <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary">submit</button>    
          <input type = "hidden" name = "_token" value="{{Session::token() }}">
        </form>
                
    </div>
@endsection
```

---

USER_CONTROLLER.PHP

```
  <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\user;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserController extends Controller {
    
    public function getDashboard()
    {
        return view('dashboard');   
        
    }
    
    public function postSignUp(Request $request){
       
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'first_name'=> 'required|max:120',
            'password'=> 'required|min:4'
        ]);
        $email = $request ['email'];
        $first_name = $request ['first_name'];
        $password = bcrypt($request ['password']);
        
        $user = new user();
        $user -> email = $email;
        $user -> first_name = $first_name;
        $user -> password = $password;
        
        $user -> save();
        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect() -> route('dashboard');
        
        
    }

    public function postSignIn (Request $request){
        
        if(Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']])) {
          return redirect()->route ('dashboard');
        }
        
        return redirect()->back(); 
    }

}


?>
```

---

Here is the stack trace of the error I receive from laravel every time I try to load the page:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\LARAVEL\LARAVEL\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\View\Compilers\Concerns\CompilesLoops.php:95

















    protected function compileFor($expression)

    {

        return "<?php for{$expression}: ?>";

    }


    /**

     * Compile the for-each statements into valid PHP.

     *

     * @param  string  $expression

     * @return string

     */

    protected function compileForeach($expression)

    {

        preg_match('/\( *(.*) +as *(.*)\)$/is', $expression, $matches);

 

        $iteratee = trim($matches[1]);

 

        $iteration = trim($matches[2]);

 

        $initLoop = "\$__currentLoopData = {$iteratee}; \$__env->addLoop(\$__currentLoopData);";

 

        $iterateLoop = '$__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop();';

 

        return "<?php {$initLoop} foreach(\$__currentLoopData as {$iteration}): {$iterateLoop} ?>";

    }

 

    /**

     * Compile the break statements into valid PHP.

     *

     * @param  string  $expression

     * @return string
```

Comment: Which line/file of the error?

Comment: I think the code you provided is not enough to find the issue as all looks good for me, you would need to provide us with the error page Laravel provide and the whole functions.

Comment: But anyway this error related to an issue of trying to access undefined index in some list

Comment: @SherifTarek Thanks for the effort in helping me solve my problem. I have provided more info about the code.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I have provided info about the stack trace of the error provided by laravel, please take a look at the code again.

Comment: You need to add a space after `->all()` in `@foreach($errors->all() as $error)`. The regex can't parse `()as` as it expects `() as`

Answer (score 0):

add space after `->all()` in `foreach` loop of your balde file and add `$request->all()` in your validate function.